# Разница в поведении std::ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Почему

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void touch(const std::string& name)
{
    if (!name.empty())
        std::ofstream f(name);
}

void main()
{
    touch("foo");
}
```

создает файл "foo", если его не существовало, а

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void touch(const std::string& name)
{
    if (!name.empty())
        std::ofstream(name);
}

void main()
{
    touch("foo");
}
```

не создает?

(Visual Studio 2015 Update 2)

Comment: Файл создается, G++ 6.1.1. Укажите версию компилятора и приложите ассемблерный листинг для обоих случаев.

Comment: Привел неполный код, обновил. Ну и уже понял почему разница в принципе.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, можете объяснить?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, пожалуйста, добавьте в пост [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (для каждого из случаев), чтобы их можно было просто взять и скомпилировать, не додумывая остальное окружение

Comment: @soon Насколько понял, во втором случае создается локальная переменная `name` с типом `std::ofstream` с конструктором без параметров.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, похоже на то. Ни разу не видел подобного использования, штудирование стандарта пока результатов не принесло

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На основании п.[8.3/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#6) Стандарта:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ( D1 )
>
> the type of the contained declarator-id is the same as that of the contained declarator-id in the declaration
>
> T D1

Получаем, что запись `std::ofstream(name);` эквивалентна записи `std::ofstream name;` Т.е. создание переменной типа `std::ofstream` с именем `name` конструктором по умолчанию, который, понятное дело, не создает никаких файлов.

Собственно это стало бы очевиднее, если убрать функцию `touch` и оставить вызов `std::ofstream(name);` прямо в `main`. Ну и IntelliSense мог помочь в определении того, что `name` внутри `if` уже имеет другой тип (`std::ofstream`), а не `std::string`.

Comment: Интересно, что например вот так: `bool exist(const std::string& name) { !!std::ifstream(name);}` открывается файл с именем `name`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian это уже не является декларацией.

Comment: Можно поподробнее. Вот это:  `std::ofstream(name);` получается декларация, а это `std::ifstream(name);` нет?

Comment: Вернее, что `return` или `!!` не дают быть декларацией этому `std::ifstream(name);` ?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian суть в наличии ! перед типом, поэтому и не декларация.

Comment: Теперь все на свои места встало, спасибо!

Comment: @VladimirGamalian return, кстати, тоже влияет на то, что запись перестает быть декларацией.

Comment: Развивая мысль, обертывание в скобки `(std::ofstream(name));` исправляет проблему второго варианта в вопросе.